# Sitting on your foot,

Tags: word-usage

What is used in English to express that someone is sitting with his weight on this feet?  I looked it up but couldn't find anything.  I don't mean kneel or squat.  **It is actually sitting with your knees bent and your weight is on your feet.**

[image]

Comment: Squatting, maybe?

Comment: I used to sit like that sometimes, when I was younger and more flexible. Usually I'd just have one foot tucked under my butt, with the other loose in front of me. I cannot think of a word or phrase that specifically means sitting on one or both of your feet.  "Lotus position" describes something similar, though, with one's feet tucked below their bent legs near the knees.

Comment: Maybe...  @MichaelHarvey...   But the images were a bit different....  They are almost standing and I don't want it to mean that...

Comment: But *squatting* ***does*** mean what you describe. (And *kneeling* often does too.)

Comment: Thete is a picture now. The person is squatting. Definitely. That is what we call that posture.

Answer (score 2):

The word you’re looking for *is* **squatting**. Squatting actually describes a range of positions from butt slightly off the ground to upright with knees only somewhat bent. Here’s an example of people doing low squats:

> [image: people squatting]
>
> [Bodyweight Squat Tutorial: Mobility Exercises to Get Low](https://gmb.io/squat/)